# How can i center a grid and align a row above with its left side?

Tags: html, css

I have a row and a grid inside a container:

CSS:

```
.container {
  display:         flex;
  flex-wrap:       wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.main-grid {
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

HTML:

```
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        // inputs here
      </div>
      <div class="main-grid">
        <div class="grid-children animated fadeIn" *ngFor="let project of projects">
        // grid children here
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

It currently looks like this(actual grid content blacked out):
[image]

So there is a row with a filter above and the grid below, both are centered as defined in the container.

But i would like only the grid to be centered and the row above start at the left side of the grid. So it should look like this:
[image]

Resized it would look like this:
[image]

I would like to know whether there is a way to center the grid below and tell the row above to start at the left side of the grid below, i was not able to do that by playing around with a container and as far as i know there is also no way to get the x-coordinate of an element which i could use to get the x-coordinate of the grid and apply it to the row.

From my testing i was only able to either center both or make both start at the left side. If i made the row start at the left side and center the grid, then the x-coordinate of the rowstart wouldnt align with the one form the grid(cause its centered).

Comment: share your HTML code

Comment: I would use another `<div>` which wraps only grid but doesn't wrap filter. If you can't do it I would try `align-self: flex-start` on filter element. Provide full code snippet example to get accurate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just define the row width as 100% and than align it to left

```
.container {
  display:         flex;
  flex-wrap:       wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.row{
    width:        100%;
    align-self:   left;
}
```

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row"><!--form--></div>
    <div class="center_content"><!--grid--></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did a few changes, The `.container` needs to be a flex container and the `.main-grid` can also be made into a flex-based container.

This can be done as follows

1. The `.container` is a column direction flex-box.
2. The `.main-grid` is a row based flex-box.

snippets:

Html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        inputs
    </div>
    <div class="main-grid">
            <div style="height:100px;min-width:80px;max-width:100px;background-color:black;border: 1px solid white;    flex: 1 1 auto;"></div>
            <div style="height:100px;min-width:80px;max-width:100px;background-color:black;border: 1px solid white;    flex: 1 1 auto;"></div>
            <div style="height:100px;min-width:80px;max-width:100px;background-color:black;border: 1px solid white;    flex: 1 1 auto;"></div>
            <div style="height:100px;min-width:80px;max-width:100px;background-color:black;border: 1px solid white;    flex: 1 1 auto;"></div>
            <div style="height:100px;min-width:80px;max-width:100px;background-color:black;border: 1px solid white;    flex: 1 1 auto;"></div>
            <div style="height:100px;min-width:80px;max-width:100px;background-color:black;border: 1px solid white;    flex: 1 1 auto;"></div>
            <div style="height:100px;min-width:80px;max-width:100px;background-color:black;border: 1px solid white;    flex: 1 1 auto;"></div>
            <div style="height:100px;min-width:80px;max-width:100px;background-color:black;border: 1px solid white;    flex: 1 1 auto;"></div>
            <div style="height:100px;min-width:80px;max-width:100px;background-color:black;border: 1px solid white;    flex: 1 1 auto;"></div>
            <div style="height:100px;min-width:80px;max-width:100px;background-color:black;border: 1px solid white;    flex: 1 1 auto;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 15px;
}

.main-grid {
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Here is a working [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/learn-html-css-001-rz2myk?file=src/app/app.component.css) for the same.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, but the problem i would like to fix still occurs here. With your approach, the row is assigned to the left side of the container and the grid is centered. The demo you presented looks like [this](https://gyazo.com/688c29a13f7b7a101a9217c405b5a8a4). But i would like the row to start at the left side of the grid, not of the container, like [this](https://gyazo.com/02764726b43b4a8bd920116501061396).

Comment: sure!! thats an easy fix. I'll just do that.

Comment: I actually managed to achieve what i wanted. The only thing i had to change in my original code, is to wrap the row and the grid in another `<div class="newWrapper">`. That `<div class="newWrapper">` is the only child of the container now. It does not even have any css. That way both the row and the grid start at the left side of the `<div class="newWrapper">`, so they are right above eachother as i wanted it. And by having the container around the `<div class="newWrapper">`, the entire thing is stlil centered. I´m sure theres an easier way to do that, but hey.

Comment: @M.Dietz so long as it solved your purpose, its great! You cracked it man! Good Job.